# Spyder Launch error after reinstalling Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I was having trouble updating my Spyder app in anaconda navigator, so I tried to uninstall and reinstall the whole thing. Now whenever I try opening Spyder from the Anaconda navigator I get a Application launch error, stating:

`/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/spyder/bin/pythonw: line 3:  4127 Segmentation fault: 11  /Users/me/anaconda3/envs/spyder/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"`

I am working on MacOs 10.14.6
Any Ideas how to fix this? 
Also I don't know too much about computers so if I forgot to give some important information, please ask.

I tried downloading Spyder as a seperate application but that won't start either and simply gives me a application launch error message. Then I also tried installing an older Spyder version from the Anaconda Navigator, but the same application launch error message was popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands

```
conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge spyder
conda activate spyder
spyder
```

Comment: Tried it, I get /Users/noahhentz/anaconda3/envs/spyder/bin/pythonw: line 3:  5081 Segmentation fault: 11  /Users/noahhentz/anaconda3/envs/spyder/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"  as a response. So basicly the same but with a different number